# OAuth Authentication for Community Customer User

Tags: apex, rest-api, oauth2

I am trying to connect from Salesforce an unrelated Salesforce instance through a community user. I can successfully authenticate using Postman, however I am having a bit of trouble converting this into a callout.

As I understand it, the right way to do this would be with a named credential and Auth Provider. However, when I enter the correct auth url (https:///customercommunity/services/oauth2/authorize) I get "Error: Endpoint must be /services/oauth2/authorize". I don't see a good way around it.

As a result, I think need to create the auth call manually. I can do this but don't see a way to avoid the user having to manually enter credentials. When I place a callout for the first part of the auth code process, I get back a link to a UI login page. Does anyone know what I'm missing?

Here's the first callout and response:

Auth URL: https:///customercommunity/services/oauth2/authorize

Params:

- response_type = code
- client_id = [clientKey]
- redirect_uri = [callbackURL]
- username = [username]
- password = [password]

Response: https://[instance]/customercommunity/login?ec=302&inst=2i&startURL=/customercommunity/setup/secur/RemoteAccessAuthorizationPage.apexp?source=[long key]